# The fastest way to Transpile TypeScript in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp

What is the best(realtime?) way to transpile Typescript for node?

I'm using WebStorm and `gulp` with task `backend:watch` running in the background that listens to the changes. So when I hit "save" in WebStorm it does transpiles TS into JS and stores under `/build` directory.

My approach works well but transpiling is time consumable, - each run takes two or three seconds, seconds become minutes, and so on.

Is there a way to optimize it, a better alternative?

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node is an alternative, but I'm
  uncertain that its better than what I currently have.
- Also, heard good about new VisualStudio based on Electron but it saves
  JS files in the same location, that looks untidy to me.

```js
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Backend tasks
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    const appSourceDir = path.join(dir, '/app');
    const appSourceGlob = `${appSourceDir}/**/*.*`;
    const appSourceRelativeGlob = 'app/**/*.*';
    const appCodeGlob = `${appSourceDir}/**/*.ts`;
    const appCodeRelativeGlob = 'app/**/*.ts';
    const appFilesGlob = [appSourceGlob, `!${appCodeGlob}`];
    const appFilesRelativeGlob = [appSourceRelativeGlob, `!${appCodeRelativeGlob}`];
    const appBuildDir = path.join(dir, '/build');
    
    
    gulp.task('backend:symlink', [], function (done) {
      const appTargetDir = path.join(dir, '/node_modules/app');
      // symlink for app
      fs.exists(appTargetDir, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          fs.symlinkSync(appBuildDir, appTargetDir, 'dir');
        }
      });
    
      done();
    });
    
    gulp.task('backend:clean', function (done) {
      clean([appBuildDir + '/**/*', '!.gitkeep'], done);
    });
    
    gulp.task('backend:compile', function (done) {
      tsCompile([appCodeGlob], appBuildDir, appSourceDir, done);
    });
    
    gulp.task('backend:files', function () {
      // copy fixtures and other non ts files
      // from app directory to build directory
      return gulp
        .src(appFilesGlob)
        .pipe(plugin.cached('files'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appBuildDir));
    });
    
    gulp.task('backend:build', function (done) {
      sequence(
        'backend:clean',
        'backend:compile',
        'backend:files',
        done
      );
    });
    
    gulp.task('backend:watch:code', function () {
      const watcher = gulp.watch([appCodeRelativeGlob], ['backend:compile']);
    
      watcher.on('change', function (event) {
        // if a file is deleted, forget about it
        if (event.type === 'deleted') {
          // gulp-cached remove api
          delete plugin.cached.caches.code[event.path];
          delete plugin.event.caches.lint[event.path];
          // delete in build
          del(getPathFromSourceToBuild(event.path, appSourceDir, appBuildDir));
        }
      });
    });
    
    gulp.task('backend:watch:files', function () {
      const watcher = gulp.watch([appFilesRelativeGlob], ['backend:files']);
    
      watcher.on('change', function (event) {
        // if a file is deleted, forget about it
        if (event.type === 'deleted') {
          // gulp-cached remove api
          delete plugin.cached.caches.files[event.path];
          delete plugin.event.caches.lint[event.path];
          // delete in build
          del(getPathFromSourceToBuild(event.path, appSourceDir, appBuildDir));
        }
      });
    });
    
    gulp.task('backend:watch', ['backend:build'], function (done) {
      // first time build all by backend:build,
      // then compile/copy by changing
      gulp
        .start([
          'backend:watch:code',
          'backend:watch:files'
        ], done);
    });
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Helpers
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    /**
     * remaps file path from source directory to destination directory
     * @param {string} file path
     * @param {string} source directory path
     * @param {string} destination directory path
     * @returns {string} new file path (remapped)
     */
    function getPathFromSourceToBuild(file, source, destination) {
      // Simulating the {base: 'src'} used with gulp.src in the scripts task
      const filePathFromSrc = path.relative(path.resolve(source), file);
      // Concatenating the 'destination' absolute
      // path used by gulp.dest in the scripts task
      return path.resolve(destination, filePathFromSrc);
    }
    
    /**
     * @param  {Array}    path - array of paths to compile
     * @param  {string}   dest - destination path for compiled js
     * @param  {string}   baseDir - base directory for files compiling
     * @param  {Function} done - callback when complete
     */
    function tsCompile(path, dest, baseDir, done) {
      const ts = plugin.typescript;
      const tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');
    
      gulp
        .src(path, {base: baseDir})
        // used for incremental builds
        .pipe(plugin.cached('code'))
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject(ts.reporter.defaultReporter())).js
        .pipe(plugin.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
        .on('error', done)
        .on('end', done);
    }
    
    /**
     * Delete all files in a given path
     * @param  {Array}   path - array of paths to delete
     * @param  {Function} done - callback when complete
     */
    function clean(path, done) {
      log('Cleaning: ' + plugin.util.colors.blue(path));
      del(path).then(function (paths) {
        done();
      });
    }
    
    /**
     * Log a message or series of messages using chalk's blue color.
     * Can pass in a string, object or array.
     */
    function log(msg) {
      if (typeof (msg) === 'object') {
        for (let item in msg) {
          if (msg.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            plugin.util.log(plugin.util.colors.blue(msg[item]));
          }
        }
      } else {
        plugin.util.log(plugin.util.colors.blue(msg));
      }
    }
```

Also published on GitHub, see https://github.com/ivanproskuryakov/loopplate-node.js-boilerplate

Comment: Unfortunately you "can't have your cake and eat it". If you want the benefits of transpilers in some form then you have to pay the price - which is waiting for compilation. A few seconds is pretty quick. The only real way to eliminate it is to not require the transpilation step (eg. just writing ES5/6). If it helps we've had a lot of success with WallabyJS (continuous test runner) running in the background to verify quality and ensure there aren't errors which helps mitigate the need for strong typing.

Answer (score 15):

Did you try just `tsc --watch` without gulp nor npm in the middle ? That is what I've found the fastest way of watch and compile my project. It takes 1 - 2 seconds the first time - but then is almost instantaneous. Get rid of all technologies you can if your objective is to be as fast as possible - even npm will take half a second - I guess gulp even more.

Also, in an other side, if you are working with multiple typescript projects, make sure you are using the new TypeScript feature Composite projects, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html - in my case I'm working with a mono-repo and several projects need to be compiled and this feature improves speed a lot and simplify the compilation workflow.

Take in mind that TypeScript is more than a compiler, it's also a Language Service - that's why -watch will do the job better than just tsc - it will perform partial compilation

Comment: Takes 1-2 secs on first run, on subsequent runs it's quite fast, since it uses incremental compilation. Seems most recent webpack plugins already leverage that, I couldnt say the same about gulp plugins since they may be outdated.

Comment: yes that's the beauty of tsc --watch it's incremental after first time. Why are you involving webpack on debugging ? if the intention is is to be as fast as possible for debug  unit-tests I strongly recommend to have the minimal number of technologies. Even npm will add half a second...  my two cents

Comment: I mentioned webpack just as an example "even with webpack it compiles quite fast".

Answer (score 1):

Update on my question - I've got fast results with fewer lines with simply by switching to `ts-node as below.

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node server.ts",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly server.ts",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register ./test/**/**/**/*.ts",
  },
  ...
}
```

`package.json` contents, more https://github.com/ivanproskuryakov/express-typescript-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Nodemon : `npm i -g nodemon`
2. Create file `nodemon.json`

   ```
   {
    "watch": ["src"],
    "ext": ".ts,.js",
    "ignore": [],
    "exec": "ts-node ./src/server.ts"
   }
   ```
3. add command In `package.json`

   ```
   "start:dev": "nodemon",
   ```